# Referencing a typedef as its struct counterpart

Tags: c, struct, nested, typedef

Ok guys, we all know there are all lot of typedef/struct questions out there, but I feel this one is a bit of a mind bender.

I'm simulating the neighbor interactions of a crystal lattice using strictly C. I have a struct called "ball_struct" which I typedef'ed as just "ball". The struct contains a pointer to a list of ball_structs (since I couldn't use the typedef name before its own declaration) that the ball considers its neighbors.

**So here's the catch:** I want to add balls to this list of list of ball_struct neighbors. When I compile (in Visual Studio 2009, no CLR support) I get:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'ball *' to 'ball_struct'

I'm not surprised, but I am stumped. Is there a way to cast the typedef back down to its respective struct? If not, is there anyway I can add a "ball" to a "ball_struct" list so I don't have to remove the typedef and paste "struct" keywords all over my code? Here's the code in question:

**The struct / typedef:**

```
typedef struct ball_struct
{
    double mass;
    vector pos, vel, acc;

    /* keep list of neighbors and its size */
    struct ball_struct *neighbors;
    int numNeighbors;
} ball;
```

**And the erroneous function:**

```
/* adds ball reference to the neighbor list of the target */
void addNeighbor(ball *target, ball *neighbor)
{
    int n = target->numNeighbors;
    target->neighbors[n] = neighbor;     // error C2440
    target->numNeighbors = n+1;
}
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated. *Remember, only solutions for C please.*

Comment: You could write: `typedef struct ball_struct ball;` and then `struct ball_struct { ...; ball * neighbours; ... };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the line where you get the error:

```
 target->neighbors[n] = neighbor;
```

you're assigning a pointer (`neighbor`) to an actual structure (not a pointer to a structure).  Note that if you look at the error message carefully, you'll see that this is what it's saying. Note the asterisk in the 'from' type it talks about:

```
cannot convert from 'ball *' to 'ball_struct'
```

Assuming that `target->neighbors` points to an array of `ball_struct` structures, I think what you want to do is:

```
 target->neighbors[n] = *neighbor;
```

---

PS: you may want to consider using the same name for your struct and the typedef of the struct:

```
typedef struct ball
{
    /* etc... */
} ball;
```

While pre-ANSI compiler might not have supported that ([Why are structure names different from their typedef names?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/26/8336829.aspx)), it's certainly well-supported today.  And I think it makes things slightly less confusing.

Comment: Or you could just have `typedef struct { ... } ball;` — but then you can't refer to `struct ball`, only `ball`.

Comment: Well, I guess that just turned out to be an excessive rant about overlooking the obvious and over-thinking my problems. That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @Brad: I should probably also ask if you have allocated space (using `malloc()` or `calloc()`, for example) for the array of `struct ball_struct` that `neighbors` is pointing to?

Comment: Yeah, I took care of that. Thanks for your concern and follow through.